# Ein Wort für das "ein- oder mehrfache" von etwas

Tags: single-word-request

Ich bin auf der Suche nach einem Wort für das **"ein- oder mehrfache"** von **etwas**, also ein Wort für das **N-fache** von **X** wobei N={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...}.

Ein **Vielfaches** von etwas impliziert mE, dass es {2, 3, 4, ...} sind und daher suche ich nach einem Wort, das explizit die 1 mit einschließt. Laut DUDEN ist ein Vielfaches zwar definiert als *"durch Multiplikation einer bestimmten natürlichen Zahl mit irgendeiner anderen sich ergebende Zahl"* und sollte daher die 1 mit einschließen, ggf. gibt es ja aber noch ein "besseres" Wort.

Was auch immer das Etwas ist, spielt zunächst keine Rolle, aber es wurde ein Kontext gewünscht: Es geht um einen Gesamtmaterialbedarf (und davon eben das ein- bis mehrfache) zur Herstellung eines Produkts. Genauer: In einer Montagelinie werden für einen Montagezyklus an einer Station Materialien benötigt (bspw. 10 Schrauben und 20 Bolzen). Ich suche nun ein Wort mit dem ich ausdrücken kann, dass die Gesamtheit des Materials, das für einen Zyklus benötigt wird ("Gesamtmaterialbedarf des Zyklus"), in ein- oder mehrfacher Menge nachgeliefert wird.

Beispielsatz: "Die Belieferung kann als ein- oder mehrfaches des Gesamtmaterialbedarfs erfolgen" bzw. "Die Belieferung kann in der ein- oder mehrfachen Menge des Gesamtmaterialbedarfs erfolgen".

Comment: Ohne Kontext ist das nicht zu beantworten, denn je nach Kontext kann *Vielfaches*, *Portion*, *Stück* ... passend sein, aber eben nicht immer. (Niemand denkt bei 5 Stück Fernsehgeräte daran, dass es auch halbe Fernsehgeräte geben könnte, bei Torte hingegen schon.)

Comment: Ich verstehe deinen Einwand nicht: es geht nicht darum, dass man bei "Stück Fernsehgeräten" denkt, dass es 0,5 Fernsehgeräte sein könnten, sondern, dass mir kein Wort einfällt, mit dem ich ausdrücken kann, dass es genau {1, 2, 3, ...} Fernsehgeräte sein können. Warum dir hier ein Kontext fehlt erschließt sich mir nicht: Was fällt dir denn für ein Wort für Fernsehgeräte ein? Ein Vielfaches von Fernsehgeräten impliziert u.U., dass es {2, 3, ...} sind.

Comment: Das beantwortet zwar die Frage nicht, aber benutze doch einfach "ein/eine oder mehrere" oder "mindestens ein/eine". Ich befürchte, es gibt kein einzelnes präzises Wort dafür.

Comment: In der Mathematik gibt es daher den Begriff "echtes Vielfaches" für k > 1

Comment: @SebastianE, nochmal anders erklärt: Ginge es um Fernsehgeräte, wäre *Stück* eine plausible Antwort, denn dann erfüllt es die geforderte Bedingung der Ganzzahligkeit (1, 2, 3, ... Stück). Ginge es hingegen um Torten, wäre *Stück* keine plausible Antwort, denn es gibt zum Beispiel halbe Tortenstücke. Kurzum, der Kontext bestimmt, ob *Stück* die Bedingung erfüllt und damit eine gültige Antwort ist oder eben nicht. Ähnliche Überlegungen gelten für Portion.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Es geht aber nicht um "Ganzzahligkeit", sondern einen Begriff (ein Adjektiv?), der sowohl "Einzahligkeit" als auch "Mehrzahligkeit" ausdrücken kann. "Mehrere Fernseher" sind immer 2 oder mehr, "ein Fernseher" ist immer genau einer, gesucht ist aber ein Begriff für "ein oder mehr".

Comment: [_Vielfachheit_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vielfachheit)?

Comment: Also wenn ich richtig verstehe: du hast eine Stückliste, die aussagt, dass man 3x, 4y und 2z für das Endprodukt benötigt, und suchst nach einem Wort, dass  aussagt: für eine natürliche Zahl n>=1 sind  vorhanden: 3n·x, 4n·y und 2n·z. Dann habe ich meine Zweifel, dass das in einem einzigen Wort formulierbar ist, *stücklistengranulare Anzahl* kommt vielleicht noch am nächsten.

Comment: Wenn man sagt, "Paul verdient ein Vielfaches von Klaus", dann kann damit auch das 3,749-fache gemeint sein - niemand wird erwarten, dass das Vielfache eine natürliche Zahl ist. Was gefällt Dir nicht an "das ein- oder mehrfache"?

Comment: @guidot in einer Montagelinie werden für einen Montagezyklus an einer Station Materialien benötigt  (bspw. 10 Schrauben und 20 Bolzen). Ich suche nun ein Wort mit dem ich ausdrücken kann, dass die Gesamtheit des Materials, das für einen Zyklus benötigt wird ("Gesamtmaterialbedarf des Zyklus") in ein- oder mehrfacher Menge nachgeliefert wird.

Comment: @Userunknown Mir gefällt daran nicht, dass es so umständlich ist, mit beschränkter Zeichenanzahl "ein- oder mehrfaches" zu schreiben. Letztendlich ist das schon "OK", aber ich wünschte, es gäbe ein Wort, das ich nicht kannte.

Comment: Du könntest schreiben "n-faches" und darauf hoffen, dass der Adressat n als natürliche Zahl > 0 auffasst. Ich schätze aber, dass Leser dann rätseln muss, und man schreibt ja, um verstanden zu werden, nicht um Tinte oder Bildschirmplatz zu sparen.

Comment: Du könntest auch zur Evolution der Sprache beitragen und "einmindest" oder "mindestein" schreiben. Vielleicht verbreitet und etabliert sich so ein Wort, bis es im Duden steht. :P

Comment: Du solltest einen konkreten Beispielsatz aufschreiben, in dem der gesuchte Begriff in Form eines ? auftaucht.

Comment: Ich vermute, dass es u.a. deswegen problematisch ist, ein natürlich-sprachliches Wort für das angestrebte Konzept zu finden, weil das "ein"-fache in natürlicher Anschauung quasi das 'Gegenteil' eines Mehrfachen ist. Das ist per Singular und Plural tief in unserer Grammatik verankert, nur die Ein-Zahl ist unter den vielen mathematisch möglichen Vielfachheiten grammatisch herausgehoben.  Ich befürchte, auch eine Formulierung wie '_es können nur n-Tupel kompletter Materialsätze bestellt werden_' wird nicht weiterhelfen, auch '_ganzzahlige Vielfache_' nicht.

Comment: Warum nicht _'Die (anderswo beschriebenen/definierten) Montagekits können in beliebiger Stückzahl geliefert werden'_? Wohl niemand wird 0 oder etwa - 4 Kits bestellen.

Answer (score 2):

Im Handel/Einkauf spricht man üblicherweise davon, dass die "Bestellung nur in ganzen Einheiten möglich" ist, wobei "Einheit" jeweils definiert werden muss. Meist gibt es einen speziellen Namen für die Einheit, oft durch die Art der Verpackung (Palette, Tray, Karton, Bund, Schachtel) oder die Art der Zusammengehörigkeit der Elemente der Einheit (z.B. "Paar" (Handschuhe, Schuhe), "Set", "Satz" (Reifen, Felgen, ...)) definiert.

Also ist es vielleicht einfacher, nach einem Namen für die Gruppierung der Teile zu suchen, anstatt sich mit dem abstrakten Konzept der n-fachheit für n>=1 zu beschäftigen. Dafür fällt mir auch in anderen Sprachen kein passendes Wort ein, das man als Fremdwort etablieren könnte.

Answer (score 0):

Ich befürchte, es gibt kein einzelnes präzises Wort dafür; daher schlage ich vor, einfach "mindestens ein/eine" oder "ein/eine oder mehrere" zu verwenden.

Ich hätte aber auch noch die ungewöhnliche Idee, sich einfach selber ein Wort zu erdenken. Natürlich müsste es dann klanglich bzw. intuitiv das vermitteln, was du ausdrücken möchtest. Da habe ich spontan "einmindest" (und Variationen) im Sinne.

Vielleicht verbreitet und etabliert sich so ein Wort, bis es im Duden steht. :P

Answer (score -3):

Du suchst das Zahlwort *etwaige*. Es ist plural, schließt aber auch den Fall ein, dass es nur um ein Ding geht.

> Um etwaigen Fehlern vorzubeugen …

Comment: "etwaig" beinhaltet auch die Nullmenge.

Comment: *Um **keinen** Fehlern vorzubeugen …* ?

Comment: vielleicht: jedwedem? Bei 'etwaig' schwing sehr viel 'Möglichkeit' mit - eben auch keiner. Ob man bei 'jedwedem' auch so argumentieren kann? Vermutlich ja, aber gefühlt nicht ganz so leicht

Comment: "Etwaig" bedeutet beim besten Willen nicht "eins oder mehrere", noch viel weniger bedeutet es "das ein- oder mehrfache". "Klaus verdient das ein- oder mehrfache von Peter" - "Klaus verdient das etwaige von Peter"? Nicht Dein Ernst!

Comment: Findest du wirklich, dass ich "die Belieferung kann als etwaiges des Gesamtmaterialbedarfs erfolgen" schreiben sollte? Das klingt für mich nicht unbedingt sinnvoll. Oder habe ich etwas nicht verstanden?

Comment: "Etwaige" ist weder ein Zahlwort noch passt es hier.